# unable to grab the last character of from a string

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I am new to bash and Linux and not sure why the last character of my selected line isn't appearing empty when it isn't empty. In my code, I am testing if the last character of my second last line == " " if so I would like to echo "yes" otherwise echo "no".

here is my code

```
Line=$(tail -n-2 file | head -n1)
echo "$Line"
echo "${Line: -1}"
if [ "${Line: -1}" == " " ]; then
    echo "yes";
else
    echo "no";
fi
```

the file consistes of:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xx x x xxx x
xxx xx xxx x
x x xxx xx .
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

the output for this is:

```
x x xxx xx .

yes
```

I am not sure why when I do `echo "${Line: -1}"` the output is empty but the output is as expected when I am doing `echo "$Line"`

any suggestions how I can fix this, thanks

Comment: PIpe the output to `sed -n l` (that's lower case `L`) to see if there's some invisible characters after that dot such as space, tab or  carriage return (if the file comes from Microsoft land)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the last character was a line terminator `\n` and the  `.` was the second last character

Comment: There are several of you all trying to solve the same piece of coursework. All hitting the same problem(s). Why not work together?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a white space in the end of the file, otherwise it won't print blank character and the condition won't cause print of "yes".

```
cat -ve <file>
```

or as others wrote

```
sed -n l <file>
```

If you want to "sanitize" (ie. strip whitespaces), I would recommend to create a separate function and process your input.

Comment: More likely a space after the dot.